Collapse/Expand Heading from Word Add-In Taskpane
I'm building a Word add-in task pane with the Yeoman Office Generator. I'm implementing expand/collapse feature for headings and their accompanying paragraphs. However, I've hit a roadblock in my search for a method or function within the Word JavaScript API that would enable me to seamlessly toggle this expand/collapse functionality.
I'm currently exploring existing properties within the Word Javascript API to determine if any of them offer the functionality to expand/collapse headings. I want to identify properties that can seamlessly integrate into the add-in I'm developing.
